# C programming do while with switch case program

Tags: c

I have been able to do switch case program but I want program to run again and again until a user selects to quit.
I basically wants program to run again and again using do while loop...

```
switch(I)
{
case 1:
    printf("67");
    break;
case 2:
    printf("45");
    break;
default:
    printf("default");
}
```

Comment: Ok, great! What doesn't work with that? What code are you using? Which language is this *actually* in? C# and objective-C are very different.

Comment: That is possible, investigate the all mighty *Infinite-Loop*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `do...while` loop like this:

```
int I = 1; //Initialize to some non-zero number to prevent UB
printf("Enter 0 to quit \n");
do{
    if (scanf("%d",&I) != 1) //If invalid data such as characters are inputted
    {
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        scanf("%*c");    //Clear the stdin
    }
} while(I!=0); //Loop until `I` is not 0
```

This piece of code will loop until the user enters 0. You can change this code according to your needs. If you want your `switch` in this, copy your posted code after the `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will run until you enter `-1` as input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int I;
    do
    {
        puts("Enter -1 to quit");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&I);
        switch(I)
        {
            case 1:
            printf("67\n");
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("45\n");
            break;
            case -1:
            puts("Bye");
            break;
            default:
            printf("default\n");
        }
    }while(I != -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this program runs untill user gives input 0 or a negative number...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int I;
    do
    {
      scanf("%d",&I);
      switch(I)
      {
        case 1:
        printf("67");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("45");
        break;
        default:
        printf("default");
      }
    }
    while(I>0);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Use of Do-While Loop.**

Choice is the variable in which user's choice will be stored, whether he wants to print the statement again or not.

```
int choice;
do{
   printf("\nHello World!");  //This is the task of the program (Replace it with your task)
   printf("\nDo You Want to Print it again ? 1 Yes/0 No: ");
   scanf("%d",&choice);
}while(choice==1); //Loop will exit when choice gets value other than 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// here switch will run until A is not equal to S


int N; 
char A;

do{
cin>>N;
N = N%7;
cout<<endl;
cin>>A;

switch(N)
    {
        case 1: cout<<"Monday"<<endl; break;   
        case 2: cout<<"Tuesday"<<endl; break; 
        case 3: cout<<"Wednesday"<<endl; break;
        case 4: cout<<"Thursday"<<endl; break;
        case 5: cout<<"Friday"<<endl; break;
        case 6: cout<<"Saturaday"<<endl; break;
        case 0: cout<<"Sunday"<<endl; break;
        
        default: cout<<"Invalid Input"; }}


while(A!='S');
```