# Is there a way to loop a switch case base program from within the switch case statement?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

So while I was practicing variations of switch-case blocks, I wanted to try and loop the Switch-Case part of the program from within which I am not able to do so far in my trials.

- I tried using continue which does not work unless the switch-case block is inside a loop.
- I tried designing a while loop with conditions, which worked but not accurately, as it did not execute the blocks inside Cases and would simply break out of the switch and terminate program successfully without executing cases.
- I tried goto but seems there are certain rules for the labels to be used which is so far does not favour the use of goto inside Switch.

My research only shows people looping the Switch-Case externally (like a Switch-Case inside a while loop or for loop etc), but could not find examples of any one trying to build a loop from within the Switch-Case block of code.
I don't mind if the solution repeats the code from beginning or starts from a external point outside Switch-Case again, but the purpose is to get the program to somehow re-execute the Switch-Case without enveloping that same Switch-Case in a loop.
I am learning C programming again after a long time hence I really did a long search for this but could not find an apt result. Maybe I am also doing a long search after a long time so I might have lost the touch.
There is a similar question but the solution given and accepted by the user indicates something different than what i am asking for here. Question :
[C programming do while with switch case program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064236/c-programming-do-while-with-switch-case-program)

Here is my code:-

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int input;

    printf( "4. Play game\n" );      //i have re-edited the question and shortened the code and included what I additionally tried as per the advice, to focus on the question more, w/o changing the main question .
    printf( "Selection: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );
    switch ( input ) 
    {
        case 4:
            printf( "Thanks for playing! Taaaa\n" );
            break;
        default: 
            while(input!=4)          //just a sample condition, and i know that it doesnt check for letters or characters as input, but that is not the point. I just want to see if a solution on similar thought/methodology exists.
           {   
            printf( "no u have to give a correct input\n" );
            scanf("%d", &input);
            continue;                // I tried a Goto and return; in this loop as well only to realize that it will not jump me out of this loop and back into the program.
           }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Alternatively, what can I do to the while loop that I used which worked inaccurately yet without errors or warnings. The while loop, as I described earlier above, did not execute the blocks inside cases but it just broke out.

The output image: [image]

Comment: Your code doesn't really check for the correct input, try typing `asdasd` and undefined behavior will occur. Also, why are you trying to do it like that?

Comment: yes i know i tried typing a letter and yes it went into an indefinite print. but that is not the point.. This is something that i can re-design and correct only after i figure out first if this basic thing that i am looking for can be possible or not. Thanks for the note any way. Btw wat is wrong with my question that it immediately recieved a negative mark

Comment: It's not really very clear, and you are asking for something that no one would try to do, so I am curious as to why you do?

Comment: @iharob i understand that, just looking out for various possibilities to try and make my learning or know-how better.

Comment: I see, but that idea must come from somwhere, some programming language you already work with, and the only way is a `goto` but that's the reason why people hate `goto`, and it's not that `goto` is useless, it's just that it's not the good choice to control the flow of the program, I remember that once I had to use a similar approach with `libssl`, from the openssl package, but I am sure it was because I was so tired that no good idea occured to me.

Comment: @iharob that was really helpfull, i guess that means i will have to learn a couple of more languages first and then try something like this. thanks a lot.

Comment: @iharob why is my question so much down voted. what is wrong with it its not a senseless thing to do is it

Comment: Your question is being down-voted because it is at best extremely difficult to understand what you are asking to do.  It simply isn't clear what you mean.  Your example code has no looping in it whatsoever.  A `switch` statement is not intended to be a loop; trying to abuse it so it works like a loop is not sensible.  But you should stop concentrating on the technology you're using and explain what you want to do.  Superficially, an ordinary `while` loop which calls an input function in the condition and reacts appropriately to the return value would do what you're likely to need.

Comment: @CodeMan if c is your first language, do not pollute your brain with another language yet, but try to search for the right resources to learn it.

Comment: @iharob yes i understand, but why so down votes though any idea? i want to improve

Comment: @CodeMan don't worry about that then, you need to worry about learning,.

Comment: @ well i am worried because stackoverflow is a good resource for clarifications and i dont want my account to be banned or barred from being able to question

Comment: IMNSHO, your stated goal _but the purpose is to get the program to somehow re-execute the Switch-Case without enveloping that same Switch-Case in a loop_ is completely misguided.  Why would you want to make a non-loop statement loop?  You can and should use loops to loop; you use a `switch` to choose between alternative actions based on some numerical criterion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well now i get the down vote reason, thanks for the edits also....will keep it in mind

Comment: @CodeMan your edited question *still* does not show how you are trying to use a loop. But please note that a loop cannot contain one or more of the `case` statements - it has to contain either the whole `switch(){...}` code block, or be contained by a single `case` statement, for example `case 2: do {...} while(condition); break;`

Comment: @CodeMan  There is such a category of participants that instead of to give an answer like to down-vote questions.:) The less qualified programmer the more othen he down-votes questions.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow hmm i could see that, they expect a beginner to do and know everything that a harvard ace-ing programmer does......but thats ok i guess it happens with gradual experience build up and impatience. Had i known all those things i wouldnt much need stack-ex would i now.

Comment: @WeatherVane i am re-editing my question to include the short version of my code that i tried. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want insane code, you can mess around with variants on this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
** DISCLAIMER
** This is an appalling idea - do not use it.
** But it seems to meet the criteria of SO 30553881.
** Maybe.
*/

extern void PlayGame(void);
extern void DesignGame(void);
extern void PlayMultiplayer(void);

int main(void)
{
    int input;

    printf("1. Play game\n");
    printf("2. Design game\n");
    printf("3. Play multiplayer\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
    printf("5. Auto-try-again\n");
    printf("Selection: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &input) == 1)
    {
redo:
        switch (input)
        {
            while (input > 0 && input != 4)
            {
            case 1:
                PlayGame();
                break;
            case 2:
                DesignGame();
                break;
            case 3:
                PlayMultiplayer();
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Taaaa!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("no u have to give a correct input\n");
                break;
            }
            if (input != 4 && scanf("%d", &input) == 1)
                goto redo;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void PlayGame(void)        { printf("%s called\n", __func__); }
void DesignGame(void)      { printf("%s called\n", __func__); }
void PlayMultiplayer(void) { printf("%s called\n", __func__); }
```

Note that the `break;` statements after the case labels break the `while` loop, not the `switch`.  You could use `continue` instead of `break`, but that would mean that the next iteration will execute `PlayGame()` and then exit the loop (because of the `break` — unless you replace that `break` with `continue`, or a `goto` of some sort, or a `return`).

### DISCLAIMER

**This is appalling code — do not use it!**

But it does show that you can do all sorts of things in C that really are insane.  You could look up [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) to see a plausibly useful chunk of code which is somewhat related to this (which is not plausibly useful).

Comment: Hey thanks a great deal for the effort, i think i am going to try experiment with this Goto redo version and check if it works. p,s, I know that defining functions was not included in my original post of question so i re changed the code to my first drafts before this code what i tried to get the work done

Comment: Hey i tried it and it works  perfectly fine to the point of answering my question And now i understand that this "not really too much insane" methodology is not plausibly usefull, but its just that there is no harm in knowing the limitations of certain features as a learner. Wow finally resumed my track after 14 hours and yes this is a perfect grid for experimenting my intentions with Switch case statements. This is very near and almost right on target to what i sort of wanted to try. a Million thanks. i spent 14 hours on this matter and is worth every second of it now.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly then you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int input;

    printf( "1. Play game\n" );
    printf( "2. Design game\n" );
    printf( "3. Play multiplayer\n" );
    printf( "4. Exit\n" );
    printf( "Selection: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );

    switch ( input ) 
    {
    do
    {
    case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
        puts( "playgame()" );
        break;
    case 2:          
        puts( "Designgame()" );
         break;
    case 3:         
        puts( "playmultiplayer()" );
        break;
    case 4:        
        printf( "Taaaa!\n" );
        break;
    default:            
        printf( "no u have to give a correct input\n" );
        printf( "Selection: " );
        scanf( "%d", &input );
    } while ( 1 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The more exact code will look

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int input;

    printf( "1. Play game\n" );
    printf( "2. Design game\n" );
    printf( "3. Play multiplayer\n" );
    printf( "4. Exit\n" );
    printf( "Selection: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );

    switch ( input ) 
    {
        do
        {
            if ( input == 1 )
            {
                case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
                puts( "playgame()" );
                break;
            }
            else if ( input == 2 )
            {
                case 2:          
                    puts( "Designgame()" );
                    break;
            }
            else if ( input == 3 )
            {
                case 3:         
                puts( "playmultiplayer()" );
                break;
            }
            else if ( input == 4 )
            {
                case 4:        
                printf( "Taaaa!\n" );
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                default:            
                printf( "no u have to give a correct input\n" );
                scanf( "%d", &input );
            }
        } while ( 1 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Though it is a valid code however it is obfuscated and not readable.

It is much better to enclose the switch statement in a do while statement. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int input;

    do
    {

        printf( "1. Play game\n" );
        printf( "2. Design game\n" );
        printf( "3. Play multiplayer\n" );
        printf( "4. Exit\n" );
        printf( "Selection: " );
        scanf( "%d", &input );

        switch ( input ) 
        {
        case 1:            /* Note the colon, not a semicolon */
            puts( "playgame()" );
            break;
        case 2:          
            puts( "Designgame()" );
            break;
        case 3:         
            puts( "playmultiplayer()" );
            break;
        case 4:        
            printf( "Taaaa!\n" );
            break;
        default:            
            printf( "no u have to give a correct input\n" );
            break;
        }
    }  while ( input < 1 || input > 4 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! the first case that u showed here in your answer is what i tried initially and yes that is obfuscated because it doesnt execute the code correctly also i tried continue and goto along with this in the similar while only to find out that it does not go for executing the cases and simply breaks out of the whole code returning zero. but finally someone has understood the line that i was thinking on and yes now i understand that there actually is now way to do what i want (atleast no formal way). Thanks a lot Vlad.

Comment: "It is much better to enclose the switch statement in a do while statement. For example", that is not a problem to me and i know that is a correct way it is just that i was looking out for possibilities since i am a learner not a pro exactly

Comment: yes i did learn more than just something today and i am very thankfull for your efforts to bring your thoughtfullness on my line of query chain in an effort to bring out a solution. And as you can see the end result of this, finally some1 actually sort of pin-pointed the actual matter and posted something on the same line of query more closer solution. Thanks a lot. Check out jonathan's post. its a little towards condition-iteration and is appalling but not too much appalling instead is interesting and nearly perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way of doing this kind of thing is using a simple `do..while` construct:

```
bool ending;
do
{
   // print menu
   // read input in variable
   // switch on your input variable, set ending to true if supposed to end
}while(!ending);
```

You discovered yourself that you can't jump out of nested loop constructs. In Java for example you can label the outer loop and do something like `break outerloop;`, but as far as I know that's the only C-like language that implements it.

So in other languages you have two options: use `goto` *properly* (using proper blocks to avoid errors about skipped constructor calls) or pull the outer loop in a separate function and `return` out of it when you want to end (which works for `main` too).

What you did in your example is exactly nothing though. There's no looping there at all.

Comment: yes thanks, in the code that i pasted i did nothing but in my trials i tried a while loop, but i didnot repeat the whole switch-case code. and your answer is fine but its the other case of what i talked about. But i do realize i believe that i have discovered myself that i cant jump out of the constructs.

Comment: I don't know what other case you're talking about. Incidentally that's why I downvoted your question, it's incredibly poorly written.

Comment: what exactly in poorly written, is it bad english or is it bold highlighting or is it illogical or should i pull down back my own question???

Comment: Well instead of bolding random words ("C programming" is useless noise, the question is already tagged), try bolding your actual question, worded as clearly as possible. Then delete everything else because it's also noise. Then remove all bolding because what's left is all important.